# Cancel content editing input request

Tags: ios, download, request, cancellation, photosframework

In my app when you download `contentEditingInput`, a user can selected a new asset, so I've tried to kill the previous request before starting a new one. Unfortunately `cancelContentEditingInputRequest:` doesn't work and I still get progress and the completion block is fired when downloading is done. `self.asset` and `self.requestId` have expected values. Problem is present when downloading an asset from the iCloud. Did I use API the wrong way?

```
if(self.requestId) {
    [self.asset cancelContentEditingInputRequest:self.requestId];
}

PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *options = [PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, BOOL *stop) {
    // update UI
};

self.asset = newAsset;
self.requestId = [self.asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
    self.requestId = 0;

    // handle content editing input
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right about me being wrong. I have used API the wrong way. `cancelContentEditingInputRequest:` is used to cancel preparing a *contentEditingInput* from an asset on the device. To cancel the download from the iCloud one should use:

```
options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, BOOL *stop) {
   *stop = YES;
};
```

It is a different topic, if the API is logical...